# RSS feature of Hippo CMS to gets feed from facet

Tags: content-management-system, hippocms

I am working on Hippo CMS, which has a [plug-in for RSS feed](http://rss.forge.onehippo.org/) 
the RSS can grab documents from existed folders. 
But I would like to implement a feature to let it grab document from facet but not real folder.
So I can do something like `news/2012/published` to get what I want. 
Anyone tried this before? Please share some idea about how I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that should be possible. You could create a hippo:facetnavigation structure and show the tree like that. Next to that you probably need to modify the default [RSSFeedBuilder](https://forge.onehippo.org/svn/rss/trunk/rss-hst-component/src/main/java/org/onehippo/forge/rss/components/RSSFeedBuilder.java) component, so that it can handle this kind of structure.

Comment: Yes you are right, I can use JCR_query command to handle the facet issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The RSS feeds on my Hippo based site are based on facets. I'm using ROME to create the feed.

You can find the code that creates the feed on:
https://github.com/jashaj/HippoWeblog/blob/master/site/src/main/java/org/onehippo/forge/weblogdemo/components/FeedCreator.java

I only use these JSPs because the HST component needs a rendering template and the feed needs to have the correct header for the content type:
https://github.com/jashaj/HippoWeblog/tree/master/site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/feeds